# How to rotate my image using Keys in pygame?

Tags: python, image, rotation, pygame, key

I'm trying to let an image (transparent image) Rotate on the keys that I press. I.E. I want to rotate my player's head up and down(he is shooting from his head), but I don't really have a decent guideline on how to code this. If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated. Also I wanted the head just to smoothly rotate(aim) up and down when I hold the keys down. Code below:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360))

background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg').convert()

player = pygame.image.load('BigShagHoofdz.png') #this must be rotateable

pygame.display.set_caption('Leslie is Lauw')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


gameDisplay.blit(background, [0,0])
gameDisplay.blit(player, [-1,223])
pygame.display.update()

FPS = 60

direction = "Down"

def head():
    if direction == "Down":
        playerhead = player
    if direction == "Up":
        playerhead = pygame.transform.rotate(player, 60)



def gameLoop():
    global direction
    gameExit = False


    while gameExit==False: 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

            if event.key == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                direction = "Up"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                direction = "Down"

clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

It should only rotate up or down when I press the up or down key, maybe let it go smooth when it's held down or up.

Comment: you have to `blit()` inside `while` in `gameloop()`

Comment: inside `head()` you will have to use `global playerhead`  or `return playerhead` because now you create local variables.

Comment: Do you just want to switch between two images, the normal and the rotated one?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to switch between a normal and a rotated image, you can create the rotated version before the while loop and then just switch the image if a key gets pressed.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 360))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# The normal image/pygame.Surface.
player_image = pygame.Surface((30, 50), pygame.SRCALPHA)
player_image.fill((0, 100, 200))
pygame.draw.circle(player_image, (0, 50, 100), (15, 20), 12)
# The rotated image.
player_rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(player_image, 60)

FPS = 60

def gameLoop():
    player = player_image
    player_pos = [100, 223]
    gameExit = False

    while gameExit == False: 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                # Assign the current image to the `player` variable.
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player = player_image
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player = player_rotated

        gameDisplay.fill((30, 30, 30))
        gameDisplay.blit(player, player_pos)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

gameLoop()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Can you add your most recent code and the image to the question? And explain a bit more detailed how the animation should look.

Answer (score 0):

so I would be using this code since your code wont actually rotate it because You are making it rotate outside of the loop (Only occurs once).

I would like you to try to use this instead:

```py
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

def rotateItem(image, angle, x,y):
    image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    imageRect = image.get_rect(center=(x,y))
    screen.blit(image, imageRect)

angle = 0
while True:
    screen.fill((r, g, b)) # Red, Green, Blue
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                angle = -angle # I can't test right now so if this doesn't work switch -angle with abs(angle)
                rotateItem(playerImage, angle, playerXPosition,playerYPosition)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                angle = abs(angle) # Same with this but change it to -angle
                rotateItem(playerImage, angle, playerXPosition,playerYPosition)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60) # Framerate
```

Also

```py
# add this if you want it to rotate by one each time it calls the function.
angle += 1
```

It should make the surface / rect rotate at the angle it is set to. I hope this helped and enjoy coding with pygame!

SOURCES:
[ClearCode - Rotating Stuff](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGsMMpAglIg)